# cognito OAuth2 flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

Where can I find information on how to use the raw HTTPS ,POST/GET, calls for AWS cognito to authenticate a user without using and SDK? I have found a page that says it can be done but there were no links to a REST API or any info on how to format the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito is really three services. Below are the links to the three REST API documents:

- [Amazon Cognito User Pools Auth API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html).
- [Amazon Cognito Federated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).
- [Amazon Cognito Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thank you, one question how long are refresh tokens good for?  or do they not expire?

Comment: @Spb2015 By default, the refresh token expires 30 days after your app user signs in to your user pool. When you create an app for your user pool, you can set the app's refresh token expiration (in days) to any value between 1 and 3650. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Comment: This is a different question. Close this question and open a new one.